# Combinatorics question about six letter sequences with repetition

Tags: combinatorics

The question I'm trying to answer is as follows:

"How many six-letter “words” (sequences of letters with repetition) are there in which the first and last letter are vowels? In which vowels appear only (if at all) as the first and last letter?"

For the first part of the problem, I got an answer of $5\cdot 26\cdot26\cdot26\cdot26\cdot5 = 11424400$.

I'm not sure this is correct because I'm not sure if some solutions are being double counted.

For the second part, I'm having trouble finding an answer. For solutions with the vowels, I think it would be $5\cdot21\cdot21\cdot21\cdot21\cdot5$, but then I'm not sure how to account for those solutions that do not have vowels.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your answer for the first part is indeed correct.

For the second part note that the first and last letter may be anything (since it could be a vowel but not necessarily) but the middle letters absolutely *cannot* be a vowel. So, we have $26\cdot 21\cdot 21\cdot 21\cdot 21 \cdot 26$

Answer (score 1):

For the first case I agree with your solution, we have

- $5^2\cdot 26^4$

For the second case we have

- $26^2\cdot 21^4$

there is not double counting because repetition are allowed.

Comment: It seems a bit ambiguous, but wouldn't you think that `ABBBBB` is an allowable sequence where only the first but not the last letter were vowels or vice versa?  If that were the case, rather than breaking into cases it would be easier to recognize the answer as $26^2\cdot 21^4$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes of course! Thanks